# GPU with Tensorflow - Pycharm

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm, gpu

I installed Tensorflow with GPU following this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

All seems fine, once the GPU is detected in the terminal. However, when opening Pycharm - and choosing as interpreter the conda environment where the installation was done - the GPU is not detected [tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')].

Anyone had a similar problem?

Because even in Pycharm terminal the GPU is detected. I already tried to add "CUDNN_PATH" and "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" as environmental variables on Pycharm but the problem remains.

Thank you